# Rstudio Checking if the current and preceding value are matching

Tags: r, match, rstudio

I am trying to check if the preceding value matching the value in the same column. So basically I want to check if df$variable[1] == df$variable[2], and df$variable[2] == df$variable[3] and so on. I have attached my code below. I have contradicting answers though. I ran a specific test case and that says they are a match, but then when I run it for the entire column it doesn't detect any matches.

```
if(FinalLR$`Revised Claim`[2072] == FinalLR$`Revised Claim`[2073]){
  print("YEP")
}

## Actual
for (i in 2:len(FinalLR$`Revised Claim`)){
  if(FinalLR$`Revised Claim`[i] == FinalLR$`Revised Claim`[i-1]){
    FinalLR$`Dist Claim#` <- 0
  } else {
    FinalLR$`Dist Claim#` <- 1
  }
}
table(FinalLR$`Dist Claim#`)
```

**Output**
[1] "YEP"

```
1
```

7070

Comment: Could you please provide a small amount of sample data to illustrate your desired result? I'm unclear if you want to check if each value matches the preceding value in the other column, or if *all* values do

Comment: Preceding Value, I DO NOT want to check all the values. Just the preceding.

Comment: No, I mean do you want to return a vector that has length one less than the input column, or do you want to return a single TRUE or FALSE repeated down the whole column? Right now you are assigning the entire column to 0 or 1 in each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `lag` comparison and convert to binary

```
library(dplyr)
FinalLR %>% 
        mutate(`Dist Claim#` = as.integer(`Revised Claim` != 
                lag(`Revised Claim`, default = first(`Revised Claim`))))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, you are missing a single ending parenthesis though